# What will my Delete helper - in Rails 3- look like for a route that's nested?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1

When I just had `resources :feedback` in my `routes.rb`, I would use this link helper that would work fine:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', feedback, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :destroy %>
```

But now, given that I have updated the route to be:

```
scope ":username" do
  resources :feedbacks
end
```

I get this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"feedbacks", :username=>#<Feedback id: 1, poster_id: 1, receiver_id: 2, content: "Test 2 is awesome", created_at: "2011-09-10 23:00:32", updated_at: "2011-09-10 23:00:32">}):
```

How do I create a link to `Delete/Destroy` using the Rails helper method to this nested resource?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always run rake routes to see what the routing system generated, in your case:

```
feedbacks GET    /:username/feedbacks(.:format) {:action=>"index", :controller=>"feedbacks"}
feedback DELETE /:username/feedbacks/:id(.:format) ....
```

<< there was wrong code snippet

**UPD**

So you helper somthing is:

```
feedback_url('username', feedback.id)
```

and link_to

```
= link_to 'Delete', feedback_url(user.name, feedback.id), :method => :delete
```

Comment: My bad...`feedback_user_url` does not work. I had that wrong in the question the first time. The correct code snippet has been added. What works is `feedback`. But that doesn't give me the right route to the right resource. How do I get the right resource for the delete method?

Comment: When I do `feedback_user_url` I get this error: `undefined method 'feedback_user_url' for #<#<Class:0x00000101d5c170>:0x00000101d4cd10>`

Comment: That doesn't work. When I do the delete, I see this in my log: `Started POST "/test/feedbacks/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-09-12 16:42:21 -0500
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/test/feedbacks/1"):` and the object doesn't get deleted.

Comment: Actually, I got it. I had to change the `:method` from `:destroy` to `:delete`.

Comment: link_to supported verbs are :post, :delete and :put. There no destroy )